# Barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm having problems making a barplot using *ggplot*.

I tried different combinations of *qplot* and *gplot*, but I either get a histogram, or it swaps my bars or it decides to use log-scaling.

Using the ordinary plot functions. I would do it like:

```
d <- 1/(10:1)
names(d) <- paste("id", 1:10)
barplot(d)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To plot a bar chart in ggplot2, you have to use `geom="bar"` or `geom_bar`.  Have you tried any of the [geom_bar example on the ggplot2 website](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html)?

To get your example to work, try the following:

- `ggplot` needs a data.frame as input. So convert your input data into a data.frame.
- map your data to aesthetics on the plot using `aes(x=x, y=y).  This tells ggplot which columns in the data to map to which elements on the chart.
- Use `geom_plot` to create the bar chart.  In this case, you probably want to tell `ggplot` that the data is already summarised using `stat="identity"`, since the default is to create a histogram.

(Note that the function `barplot` that you used in your example is part of base R graphics, not `ggplot`.)

The code:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1/(10:1))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]