# I need sum values NOT count values in my bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]

I have the following dataset and I need to do a simple bar chart (preferably with ggplot).

I ran the following code

```
top_10_visualised <- ggplot(quantity_greater, aes(CashierName)) + geom_bar()
```

but I simply get a count of the number of cashiers and not the actual quantity.

Can someone help out, please?

Comment: `top_10_visualised <- ggplot(quantity_greater, aes(CashierName, Quantity)) + geom_col()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465066/barplot-in-ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Ronak Shah in the comments, you need to specify both x and y axis variables to your ggplot by `aes(x=CashierName, y=Quantity)`. If you don't specify y axis variable, the count of the number of cashiers is displayed by default.

Comment: Glad to help. If an answer helped you, don't hesitate to mark it as answered so that people won't think it needs attention.