# Plotting dplyr summarised tibble using ggplot using column names

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a summarise output containing a single value per column in R, such as:

```
A      B      C      D
0.25   0.13   0.19   0.30
```

I would like to select some of the columns by name and then plot its corresponding value in ggplot.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
A = c(24,25,26)
B = c(12,13,14)
C = c(18,19,20)
D = c(29,30,31)

df = data.frame(A,B,C,D)

df %>%
  summarise(across(c(A,C),
                   ~mean(.)/100
  ))

>     A      C
   0.25   0.19
```

I would then like to use ggplot to plot two bar charts where the x-axis contains A and C, and the Y axis is a bar chart of the values 0.25 and 0.19 respectively.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [barplot in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465066/barplot-in-ggplot)

Comment: If the question is just how to make a bar chart, you'd do well to start with some ggplot tutorials, and then come back to SO with specific problems in fixing that code. There are a lot of good ones, including the ones linked to in the ggplot docs site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that `ggplot2` may perhaps need on its cover - **Don't think in terms of excel**

```r
A = c(24,25,26)
B = c(12,13,14)
C = c(18,19,20)
D = c(29,30,31)

df = data.frame(A,B,C,D)
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  summarise(across(c(A,C),
                   ~mean(.)/100
  )) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling as I had no idea you could use "name" and "value" as inputs for aes()

Comment: @jp1 I think you haven't understood it yet.  The idea is to reshape the data so that the axis may turn into one variable and values into another.  You may read the concept of `tidy` data [here](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) before proceeding further  :)