# I've populated a histogram in R showing summed Revenue by Sector, as my revenue is in billions, how can I get by bars to be show in their entirety?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

```
Sector                Revenue 
Financial Services    19186520752672  
Energy                14332965232156   
Consumer Cyclical     14283071830539
Technology            11285197688609
```

I have the below code:

```
sectors1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sector)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#97b3c6")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Sector",
       y = NULL,
       title = "Revenue by sector")
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQlM9.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you please `dput()` your `sectors1` and paste the result into a code block in your original question?  It may be something to do with the data format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Barplot in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465066/barplot-in-ggplot) - you also need a `y` aesthetic which in your case should be `Revenue`.